# I need an advanced CSS code explanation

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Some old YouTube creator posted this as something he would do and I have never seen code like this before:

```
a[href]:not([href*="#"]):after {
    content:" - " attr(href);
}
```

He's not available to ask and this code looks pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Style every `:after` pseudo element of every `<a>` tag which `href` attribute does not contain `#` character, so it's content is a *whitespace* +*dash* + *whitespace* + `<a>`'s href attribute:

```css
a[href]:not([href*="#"]):after {
    content:" - " attr(href);
}
```

```html
<a href="href-attribute">With following dash</a> <br>
<a href="#href-attribute">Without following dash</a>
```

Selectors explained:

- [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)
- [[attribute]](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/:not)
- [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/:after)